# Cassandra Replicates data on all nodes when RF = 2

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I've set up a Cassandra Cluster with 4 nodes in total with 2 nodes being seed nodes and the other 2 being normal nodes. I've set replication factor as 2.

Here is my **cassandra.yaml**. Apart from the following values, every setting remains the same default value.

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

I installed cassandra on all my 4 nodes with the above configuration (ofcourse having different listen_address)

Next, I ran the `sync_tables.py` file on all the 4 nodes.

Following is the `sync_tables.py` file

```
connection.setup(CLUSTER_NODES_LIST, "mad")

create_keyspace_simple("mad", replication_factor=2)
models_list = []
sync = True
if sync: 
    for model in models_list:
        sync_table(model)
```

It created KEYSPACE 'mad' and N column families.

Now when I fired a  query to insert a data on `seed1`, it replicates the data on all the 4 nodes. **Why is this?** I set my RF as 2, then also its getting replicated on all the 4 nodes.

when I did `DESCRIBE KEYSPACE mad;`, it results as follow:-

```
CREATE KEYSPACE mad WITH replication = {
  'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
  'replication_factor': '2'
};
```

which clearly shows that RF has been set as 2. Is this a normal behaviour. **Why is it getting replicated on all the 4 nodes even when RF is set as 2.**

Comment: What makes you think the data is replicated on all four nodes? Data can be queried from any node, but only two nodes actually contain the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is only replicated to two nodes, but you can read/write from any in the cluster. See [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/architectureClientRequestsRead_c.html) for more information on request coordination.

To check which nodes in the cluster have replicas, you can use nodetool:

```
nodetool getendpoints <keyspace> <table> <key value>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a 4 node cluster When you set the replication_factor as 2 when creating the keyspace, the data is only replicated to two nodes, but you can read/write from any node in the cluster. When you query data you will be able to see data on all nodes, that does not mean that the data is replicated on all nodes.

Note: nodetool getendpoints returns the nodes that are supposed to store data having that key. It works with any key even if the key does not exist in the cluster. It does not check if the data is present anywhere.